# Hide column toggle

Tags: excel, vba

Need some direction, I have data in hierarchical order in Excel. * or 0 is basically some data, and x is basically empty cell, but it denotes as child data. I would like to assign a single button, and hide all the data 1st and display one by one from root to child.

Analogy: assuming you have to take a look at drive. so 1st we will visit the root folder and list out the items. now from this list we will visit 1st item and list out 2nd level ONLY of sub-items. once a new list is made, we will move back and visit the 2nd root item and lists their sub-items (only 2nd level). we can continue till the last root folder. once this done we will do the same for 3rd...4th...5th..nth levels.

```
Input:
    *           
    x   *       
    x   *       
    x   x   *   
    x   x   x   *
    x   *       
    x   *       
    0           
    x   0       
    x   0       
    x   x   0   

Output step0:
Hide all the row + column

Output step0.5:
* (root/1st column - 1st element excluding x Basically Column A)

Output step1:
* (root/1st column - 1st element excluding x)
0 (root/1st column - 2nd element excluding x)

Output step n:
* (root/1st column - 1st element excluding x)
0 (root/1st column - 2nd element excluding x)
:
:
:
:
:
y (root/1st column - n-1 element excluding x)
z (root/1st column - n element excluding x)

Output step1:
*
0

Output step2:
*   
x   *
0   

Output step3:
*   
x   *
x   *
0
```

Output step4:
    *
    x   *
    x   *
    x   *
    0

and so on as per the image:

[image]

```
Output step7:
data will keep expending till the same as Input data.

Output Step8:
Data will keep shrinking in reverse order. like step 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -1.
```

Experimental code:

```
Sub Hide_Next()

Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range
'Need help with dynamic range. 

    For Each a In Range("A1:A23").Cells
        For Each b In Range("B1:B23").Cells
        If a.Value <> Empty And b.Vaule = Empty Then
                a.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        Next b
    Next a

End Sub
```

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: In my view you should flatten your data i.e. add a column or columns to left which include data on the context within the hierarchy. It might make the over all use-case simpler.

Comment: In the example, * and 0 are data in each cell. x is basically a blank cell, x-cell used to distinguish parent/child relationships..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here below the example code, where I put also comments to understand.

`DoAStep` is the macro you have to link to the button. 
`exp_rng` is the range that contains your 'structure' to expand. You can write a code to let VBA understand which is the range using the information you know about the structure.

When you have all the rows hidden you know you have to expand, when you have all the rows visible you know that you have to come back hiding them, while when you are in the middle steps you know what you have to do only remembering what you are doing at the steps before.
Then I use the `is_expanding` variable in the module scope: its value remain stored between DoAStepp calls. But when you open the excel file `is_expanding` has `False` as default. If you want to store the expanding/reducing direction you have to store it inside a cell value.

```
Dim exp_rng As Range
Dim is_expanding As Boolean

Sub DoAStep()
    'You can set Range one time for all if you want and you can also 'calculate' it without writing 'A1:D11' in the code
    Set exp_rng = Range("A1:D11")

    'Direction engine: when expanding calls expand-step.
    'If the expand step doesn't find anything to expand then reverse the direction
    'Same for reduction

    If is_expanding Then
        If Not ExpandOneStep Then
            is_expanding = False
            ReduceOneStep
        End If
    Else
        If Not ReduceOneStep Then
            is_expanding = True
            ExpandOneStep
        End If
    End If

End Sub


Function ExpandOneStep() As Boolean

    Dim i_row As Long, i_col As Long


    'Loop through cells, from top to bottom, from left to right
    'exp_rng(i_row, i_col) is the cell I'm looking
    For i_col = 1 To exp_rng.Columns.Count
        For i_row = 1 To exp_rng.Rows.Count

            'When we are expanding we search for hidden cell ( = cells in an hidden row) to unhide
            If exp_rng(i_row, i_col).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then

                'Check if the cell has a value (I'm checking if it's not empty and not "x", you can change with whatever you want
                If Not IsEmpty(exp_rng(i_row, i_col).Value) And exp_rng(i_row, i_col).Value <> "x" Then

                    'Unhide the row and exit the function so that we will not unhide other rows (leaving them for next steps)
                    exp_rng(i_row, i_col).EntireRow.Hidden = False


                    'Exit the function returning TRUE in order to say "I found something to unhide".
                    'When we don't find anything to unhide then we have to change expanding with reducing
                    ExpandOneStep = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If

        Next i_row
    Next i_col

    'If the for loop ends then we have not found any row to unhide so we
    'have to switch to 'reducing time' instead of expanding

    ExpandOneStep = False
End Function


Function ReduceOneStep() As Boolean

    Dim i_row As Long, i_col As Long

    'ReduceOneStep is like ExpandOneStep but:
    ' - Loop from right to left, from bottom to top (reverse loop)
    ' - Check for unhidden rows to hide

    For i_row = exp_rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        For i_col = exp_rng.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

            If exp_rng(i_row, i_col).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                If Not IsEmpty(exp_rng(i_row, i_col).Value) And exp_rng(i_row, i_col).Value <> "x" Then
                    exp_rng(i_row, i_col).EntireRow.Hidden = True

                    ReduceOneStep = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If

        Next i_col
    Next i_row


    ReduceOneStep = False
End Function
```

Comment: Igor! There is no enough word express! but many 10x for the time and support. It's more than what I was looking for! Extremely helpful.

Comment: Just wondering if there is a quick way to add a hotkey for example F10, I know with macro we can assign a combination key. could not make it work with a single function key?

Comment: Running once the code line below you will attach the macro execution to the F10 key press.
`Application.OnKey "{F10}", "DoAStep"`

But another solution is to link the macro to a real 'button' in the GUI ribbons. Like https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/add-a-macro-to-the-toolbar.html

Comment: Just wondering if google spreadsheet app script can be leveraged instead Excel. Mainly if the F10 key press can be attached with app script ?